# System.Data.EntityProxies group by keeps doing tons of selects GroupBy linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I have inherited this project where it is using dynamic proxies for EF6. From a repo it returns IqueryAble(proxyObject).
I can watch SQL profiler and see it returns 6000+ records.. great! so far so good. 
At this point I then create 3 lists aginst that dataset (say 3 X 2000 records) 
Because each of those has filter logic I can also see a call to the db to return the list. Great! So far 4 calls to the DB and 6000 records.

THE PROBLEM
Every time I run this group by... I get 2000 calls to the DB! One Call for each record in Sublist.  My guess it because it needs to inflate the object each time? Its terribly slow however.

```
var lts = Sublist.GroupBy(p => p.proxyObject.ProvinceCode)
            .Select(n => new CountModel()
            {
                TypeName = n.Key,
                ItemCount = n.Count()
            }).ToList();

        PresentationModel.AddRange(lts);
```

Comment: What is the type of `Sublist`?

Comment: I ended up resolving this issue by Selecting into a new POCO directly. What was happening was that because the entity was a combination of a bunch of underlying repos...it ended up that EF was just creating a s#@ton of individual queries and then rolling them up.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up resolving this issue by Selecting into a new POCO directly. What was happening was that because the entity was a combination of a bunch of underlying repos...it ended up that EF was just creating a ton of individual queries and then rolling them up

```
 var last3Months =
            ProxyEntity.Where(l => DateTime.now() <= l.EffectiveDate)
                .Select(l => new ModelMicro()
                {
                    x= l.x,
                    y= l.y,
                    z= l.z
                });
```

This resulted in one single call to the db returning 6000 rows that I could then shift where i needed. I then grouped on z in my underlying return. Most likely ways to make it better.